# Fetching data from sql database row 2 column 4

Tags: php

I have a database with 2 rows and I need to fetch information mostly from row 1 which works with the code below, but also need to fetch data from a column in row 2. I'm not exactly sure what the command is to focus fetching on that certain row + column.

```
$query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM myData WHERE dateNext >= NOW() ORDER BY id ASC");

 $entryPhase = $query->fetchColumn(1);
 $dateEnd = $query->fetchColumn(5);
 $textEN = $query->fetchColumn(2);
 $textFR = $query->fetchColumn(3);
 $nextPhase = $query->fetchColumn(8)
```

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a relational database rows don't have an order or numbers. What you mean is the row with 'id = 1' and 'id = 2', or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have slightly misunderstood `fetchColumn`. This may be unexpected based on its name, but it will actually fetch a row from your result set. It just returns the specified column from that row. So each time you call it, you're fetching the specified column from a new row.

If you know you have two rows, you can probably just use `fetchAll` to get both rows in an array and then get whatever data you need using multidimensional array indexes.

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();
$row2Column4 = $results[1][3];  // 1 and 3 rather than 2 and 4 because of 0-based indexes
```

I would recommend using an associative or object fetch style instead, though, so you can get the value using the column name instead of a numeric index.